# What is 'this' keyword in .cshtml file and how to use .cshtml code in a .js file

Tags: javascript, razor, view, this

Can someone let me know what does "this" keyword do here and what is this self.model.get() method? I 
want to use the below line of code for "assc" variable in a .js file. How can I do this?

```
    //var assc = _.find(self.model.get("associations"), { "associationName": data.associationName });

    //below is a .cshtml file code snippet

    function AssociationsViewModel(associations) 
     {
        var self = this; 
        var ListPageSize = 5;
        var associationInstancesPageSize = 6;
        var currentAssociation = null;
     }

    self.onAddAssociationClicked = function (eventArgs, data) 
     {
      var assc = _.find(self.model.get("associations"), { "associationName": data.associationName });
            if (assc) 
            {
                if (assc.isAddNewEnabled) 
                 {
                    addInstanceToAssociation(self.model, assc);
                 }
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

this keyword is for containing class, here this class is stored in a variable self, and when you are trying to do self.get It is calling get method on containing class of the function.

In javascript or typescript this is done to separate access to containing class when sometimes this can refer to window this variable